# Find a specific thread and access its method C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I'm trying to find a thread in a list of threads by querying its `threadId` and access the function in that specific thread.

So when a user inputs price from frontend, it will execute `CreateThread()` and create a new thread and add it to the thread list.

```
List<Thread> lstThreads = new List<Thread>();

public static Thread Start(MyClass myClass) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => { myClass(); });
    thread.Start();
    return thread;
}

public IActionResult CreateThread(int price) 
{    
    var thread = Start(new MyClass(DoWork(price)));
    lstThreads.Add(thread);
}
```

```
public class MyClass 
{
   bool stop = false;

   private void DoWork(int price)
   {
       while(!stop)
       {
           // Do work here
       }

       if (stop) return;
   }

   public void Stop()
   {
       lock (stopLock) {
           stop = true;
       }
   }
}
```

When a user of the thread now wants to stop the while loop in `DoWork()` by calling `Stop()`, how can this be done? User knows the `threadId` by the way.

Comment: but `Abort()` is not the proper way to do it as there is no guarantee that the process will actually stop plus raising an exception.

Comment: How about a setup where you create a `CancellationTokenSource` for each thread and store it all in a `Dictionary<Thread, CancellationTokenSource>` instead of this list. That way you can lookup the thread in the `Dictionary` and call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` on the `CancellationTokenSource` of that thread?

Comment: And ofcourse the `DoWork` needs to handle the cancellation appropriately.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel here.You should probably be using a higher-level library, such as the [DataFlow Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). It doesn't look like you've yet learned enough about parallel programming to write low-level stuff yourself. For example, you are locking on an object to set a bool, but setting a bool is an atomic operation that doesn't need a lock. For another example, you need to use Volatile.Read() and Volatile.Write() to access the bool, to avoid issues.

Comment: @Knoop sounds easier for me to do it your way

Comment: First, you should avoid creating threads directly unless you have some sort of specific need for that. .NET has a `ThreadPool` class that you should use in most cases, which then allows it to manage your thread lifetimes (which is a beast that will almost assuredly eat you alive if you try to do it yourself and don't know exactly what you're doing). However, even then, in a web app context, the app itself has a thread pool, so any threads you create are coming out of that pool. That pool is also what's used to service requests.

Comment: Every thread you create decreases your possible server throughput. In other words, creating threads in a web app is counter productive. You're decreasing performance, not increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is such a 1999 approach. If you have the ability to use Tasks and/or async/await do use them! They are far more efficient.
Now, if you must use threads you could create/start the thread in MyClass and keep a reference to it then calling Stop on that:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private volatile bool stop = false;
    private volatile int price;
    private Thread myThread;

    public MyClass(int price)
    {
        this.price = price;
        myThread = new Thread(DoWork);
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        while(!stop)
        {
            // Do work here
        }

        if (stop) return;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

...

```
List<MyClass> lstMyThreads = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var myT in lstMyThreads)
    myT.Stop();
```

But I need to say this again: **if possible use Tasks and CancellationToken**.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about `CancellationToken` Do you mind if I can get a snippet of code when using Tasks and CancellationToken?

Comment: You can find good examples on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation . Please do take the time to study this as it can be the source of a lot of serious bugs.